# how to loop a variable name within a list

Tags: r

I am working with a list, I want to loop a variable several times but I can't.

This is the example:

```
a=data.frame(ID=1:5,WT=1:5)  
b=data.frame(ID=101:105,WT=101:105)
c=list(a,b)
names(c)=c("P01","P02")
```

Now I want to add a new column to each data frame

```
c$P01$seq=1:length(c$P01$ID)  
c$P02$seq=1:length(c$P02$ID)
```

The problem that I got is that my list has 29 data frames, not two like in this example. How can I automatise this process, so I can add a new column to each data frame?

I've tried few things with no success like creating a loop, but it doesn't not work:

```
unique=names(c)
for (i in 1:length(unique) {
   c$unique[i]$seq=1:length(c$unique[i]$seq)  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `seq_along` with `lapply`

```
lapply(c, transform, Seq = seq_along(ID))
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
c %>% 
   map(~ .x %>% 
            mutate(Seq = row_number()))
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I've been stucked in this for a long time. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

The reason, why your `for`-loop is not working, is that you are using a `character`-value in combination with the `$`-operator. You can fix this by indexing the list with `[[` instead.

```
df_names <- names(dfs)
for (i in seq_along(df_names)) {
  dfs[[df_names[i]]]$seq <- seq_along(dfs[[df_names[i]]]$ID)
}
```

Further you can use the names itselves in the `for`-loop:

```
for (x in df_names) {
  dfs[[x]]$seq <- seq_along(dfs[[x]]$ID)
}
```

**Data**
*Note: As c and unique are two functions in base R I changed the variable names in my example.*

```
a <- data.frame(ID = 1:5, WT = 1:5)
b <- data.frame(ID = 101:105, WT = 101:105)
dfs <- list(a, b)
names(dfs) <- c("P01", "P02")
```

Comment: Thank you for your kind explanation about the loop. It works now.